# Not Equals Replacement for Aerospike

Tags: java, predicate, aerospike

Since PredExps have been deprecated since aerospike client version 6.x.x onwards for Java, what is the corresponding Filter Expression replacement for the notEquals functionality that PredExps provided?

For example:

```
predicate = Arrays.asList(PredExp.stringBin(key), PredExp.stringValue(String.valueOf(value)),PredExp.stringEqual(),PredExp.not());
```

What is the Filter Expression equivalent of this?

I tried using a combination of Filter Expression for this but even that is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Aerospike Filter Expression for "not equal" is `ne`, checkout: https://docs.aerospike.com/server/guide/expressions/comparison#ne

Also a good place to look is the Aerospike Java Client project on GitHub: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java
It contains some tests and code examples that uses `ne`.

For example, the code below find records where bin `age` is not an integer.

```java
Expression exp = Exp.build(
  Exp.ne(Exp.binType("age"), Exp.val(ParticleType.INTEGER)
```

For your case it would be something like:

```java
Exp.ne(Exp.stringBin("binName"), Exp.val("stringValue"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Roi. One small problem here though is that your solution specifies using the Expression class whereas i want to use the Filter class to achieve the same behaviour. Would that be possible?

Comment: You mentioned Filter Expression, which you set via Expression class in the QueryPolicy.
Filter class is part of the Statement class and its a filter which utilizes a secondary index (make sure you have a secondary index on the field you wish to query)
An example of setting a Filter: 
Statement stmt = new Statement();
stmt.setNamespace(namespace);
stmt.setSetName(set);
stmt.setFilter(Filter.equal(binName, "value"));
RecordSet rs = client.query(null, stmt);
You can also read about secondary index based query on: https://developer.aerospike.com/client/usage/queries/basic/secondary